# Cannot use Mechanize in Rails app: NameError: uninitialized constant Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have added a gem:

```
gem 'mechanize'
```

And bundled them:

```
bundle
```

I see in gemfile.lock:

```
mechanize (2.7.5)
  domain_name (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.1)
  http-cookie (~> 1.0)
  mime-types (>= 1.17.2)
  net-http-digest_auth (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
  net-http-persistent (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.2)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6)
  ntlm-http (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.1)
  webrobots (>= 0.0.9, < 0.2)
```

So I open `rails console`

```
irb(main):001:0> Nokogiri
=> Nokogiri
irb(main):002:0> Mechanize
NameError: uninitialized constant Mechanize
        from (irb):2
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /mnt/f/Nauka/crawler/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

What am I supposed to do? Everything is set and rails app doesn't see Mechanize. I'm working on win10 bash, ruby 2.4.0, rails 5.0.3

Comment: Does mechanize work manually required in irb with `require 'mechanize`?

Comment: Could this be because you've done something "odd" like bundle with the wrong ruby version, or reloading a stale rails console, or bundled/opened the console in a different project, .... It might be worth a quick sanity check.

Comment: you should really do that, I tested a nearly identical setup and it worked without problems.

Comment: @Niklas It does.

Comment: I have a feeling that I already checked everything @TomLord. @Niklas does ```require 'mechanize'``` working mean anything?

Comment: I wanted to see if you got mechanize to work on windows :) Maybe run `bundle update`

Comment: @Niklas I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux so it's not exactly windows.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak Sanity check: Can you `bundle show mechanize`, and retry the above with `bundle exec rails console`?

Comment: @TomLord ```bundle show mechanize```: ```/home/viters/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5```, ```bundle exec rails console```: ```irb(main):001:0> Mechanize
NameError: uninitialized constant Mechanize```

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak Can it be spring? Have you stopped spring manually `spring stop`?

Comment: ^ This would be my next guess too. See my original comment, *"reloading a stale rails console"*

Comment: You were right, it was something with caching (it is what spring does, doesn't it?). I typed 'spring stop' and everything froze (maybe I shouldn't do it while server is running?). So I restarted my PC - now it works. I forgot about this standard solution to every problems. I would gladly give one of you an accepted answer if you could explain how it is possible that console was reloaded with nokogiri, but it didn't see mechanize.

Comment: Btw. thank you very much.

Comment: You should not run spring for anything except development/test and yes stopping the server before killing spring is a good idea.